# Gulp Task Breaking on Angular Files

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I have the gulp task set up and running to create an Angular app, and it runs  without error and creates the files correctly, but when I load the page on a browser, I get following error messages.

Is there some step or some plugin I'm missing to get the Angular files to all "work"?  I've used the angularFilesort() and ngAnnotate() plugins already.

```
var bower = gulp.src(bower_files)
    .pipe(concat("bower-expanded.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.prod))
    .pipe(rename("bower.js"))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.prod + paths.js));        

// gather and compress the app's js files 
var app = gulp.src(paths.source + "app/**/*.js")
    .pipe(angularFilesort())
    .pipe(concat("app-expanded.js"))
    .pipe(ngAnnotate({          
          add: true,
          single_quotes: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.prod))
    .pipe(rename("app.js"))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.prod + paths.js));
```

The errors are

```
TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function
(function(angular) {
```

which points to these lines of code

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';

  /**
   * Called with an array this acts like map, otherwise it acts like _.mapValues
   * in lodash.
   * @return {Array|Object} The same type as the input argument.
   */
  var mapValues = function(obj, callback) {
    if (angular.isArray(obj))
```

The other error is

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angularSpinner due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'angularSpinner' is not available! 
You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. 
If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$injector/nomod?p0=angularSpinner
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I notice you're not running `ngAnnotate` on your bower components, but you are running `uglify` on them. This could be causing your problem.

Try:

```
var bower = gulp.src(bower_files)
    .pipe(concat("bower-expanded.js"))
    .pipe(ngAnnotate({          
      add: true,
      single_quotes: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.prod))
    .pipe(rename("bower.js"))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.prod + paths.js));
```

As an aside, it's not an awesome idea to concatenate all of your dependencies into a single file. The browser can handle asynchronously loading multiple JS files and will do so much faster than loading a single, massive JS file.

Answer (score 0):

After reading through various answers in SO the first error usually refers to a forgotten `;` in the lines prior to the error.
You can configure the concat task to use `;` as a seperator for js files to avoid this.

On the second I agree with @ShaunScovil, also using the `.min` files provided from each bower package is safer.

You can make use of this [main-bower-files](https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files) package to set this up depending of the `env` and automate the process of building one or more files of all bower dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

This same thing happens with GruntJS and I recently learned how to fix it. Make sure all of your angular js controllers, directive and filters have proper includes on them.

Example wont work:

```
angular.module('uniApp').directive('autoFocus', function ($timeout) {
   return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.autoFocus,
      function (newValue) {
          $timeout(function () {
              element.focus();
          });
      }, true);
   };
});
```

Notice on the above how the $timeout is not properly included?

Example will work:

```
angular.module('uniApp').directive('autoFocus',['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
   return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.autoFocus,
      function (newValue) {
          $timeout(function () {
              element.focus();
          });
      }, true);
   };
}]);
```

Now the $timeout is properly included. Make sure to check this little detail on all controllers, filters, and directives.

Comment: That is what ngAnnotate does.

Comment: @Shaun Scovil I was unaware of ngAnnotate. Thanks for telling me, I will have to check that out.